# Keno UI TreeView and JSON object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to convert my sample XML file as JSON object and set that as a datasource to my tree view control. Its not working. I am sure that I am missing something here but not sure what's that. Please help me.

Here is my code in Controller class where I am loading the XML file and retruning as JSON

```
        public JsonResult Employees()
        {

            XElement xdoc = XElement.Load("C:\\Users\\a409114\\Desktop\\TreeView.xml");
            return Json(xdoc, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Here is my code in the view file where I am invoking the action name "Employees" in my controller class "TreeViewController".

```
<div class="demo-section">
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("treeview")
     .DataTextField("vehicles")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read
            .Action("Employees", "TreeView")
        )
    )
)
</div>

<style scoped>
.demo-section {
    width: 200px;
}
</style>
```

Here is my sameple XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tree>
<vehicles>
    <car>FM-1100</car>
    <car>FM-4200</car>
    <bike>FM-3100</bike>
</vehicles>
<personnel>
    <client>GH-3000</client>
    <vip>GH-3100</vip>
</personnel>
</tree>
```

This is not working for me. Please Help!